# Triple Monitor Setup (Portrait) viewing angle mod?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have 3x Samsung 2443BW (each 24") and would like to use them all in portrait, but I can't because the viewing angle is so bad. In one angle I can't see anything, in another it's all perfect but I can't move my head:

[image: img]

How to mod the display transparencies to get a normal image? Or is that not realisable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can 'mod' an LCD to improve its viewing angles, as it's a consequence of the physical composition of the display's material.

This won't be helpful, but you should have checked what the specification said about viewing angles before choosing those displays. :-(

Since your displays are Samsungs, have you seen their selection of [Wide Viewing Angle Monitors](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/wide-viewing-angle-monitors)?

Quoting a [CNET Monitor Buying Guide](http://www.cnet.com/topics/monitors/buying-guide/):

> **In-plane switching (IPS)**
>
> IPS-based monitors are usually the most expensive [...]. They also tie
>   with PLS [see below] for the best viewing angles of all the
>   technologies and produce the most accurate colors; however, their
>   blacks are not as deep as VA panels'. IPS monitors are the slowest of
>   the bunch in both response time and input lag.
>
> **Plane-line switching (PLS)**
>
> [The] first monitor to make use of [PLS] was the Samsung SyncMaster
>   S27A850D. PLS panels sport viewing angles as wide as IPS, while
>   offering higher brightness at a lower cost in power consumption.

You might also find [ZDNet: How LCD makers lie to you about viewing angles](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-lcd-makers-lie-to-you-about-viewing-angles/) interesting.

Comment: I'm half certain reading somewhere that TNs have worse reading angles in portrait orientation as well.

Comment: Well, I don't know of any monitors whose display panels are _designed_ for portrait mode; they're probably (nearly) all of them designed for landscape use regardless of whether or not their casings allow for it.